# Bitshift Encrypt and Decrypt with Circular shift in Python

Tags: encryption, python-3.4

Edit: I figured it out. Here is the code I used.

```
def bitshiftEncrypt(word):
    newWord = ""
    for i in word:
        shift = '{:07b}'.format(ord(i)+1)
        newShift = shift[1:]
        newShift += shift[0]
        newWord += chr(int(newShift,2))
    print(newWord)

def bitshiftDecrypt(word):
    newWord = ""
    for i in word:
        shift = '{:07b}'.format(ord(i))
        newShift = shift[len(str(shift))-1]
        newShift += shift[:-1:1]
        newWord += str(chr(int(newShift,2)-1))
    print(newWord)
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bin()` will give you the shortest possible representation. This will screw you over in various ways.

```
3>> bin(3)
'0b11'
3>> '{:07b}'.format(3)
'0000011'
```

Comment: I am confused. The way I am using bin()[2::] cuts off the 0b for the binary, so I can circular shift it. Is that not the best route to go?

Comment: 0b100001
0b1111010
That may be an issue. :p I overlooked that. Let me take a look at my code some more.
So, when I am decrypting it, it is shifting wrong, because there are the wrong number of bits.